# Redirect String .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, redirect

I am new on .htaccess and want to redirect URL from .htaccess

like:

http://test.example.com/abc/xyz/456adf646asdf

to

http://test.example.com/abc/xyz?id=456adf646asdf

or
http://test.example.com/abc/xyz/?456adf646asdf

Please help.

I tried this:

RewriteRule ^(.+)/abc/xyz/$ /abc/xyz?id=$1

but did not work for me..

Comment: didn't you tried anything?

Comment: I tried, but did not work for me..RewriteRule ^(.+)/ride/linkedin/$ /ride/linkedin?id=$1

Comment: edit your question and update with your example

Comment: done. please check question.

Comment: try `RewriteRule ^/ride/linkedin/(.+)$ /ride/likedin?id=$1`

Answer (score 1):

You should also have a RewriteCond to match the incoming URL pattern. Try this to match you explicit case.

```
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/abc/xyz/(.\*)
 RewriteRule (.\*) /abc/xyz?id=%1 [L]
```

There are of course lots of options. You could also try

```
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.\*)/(.\*)/(.\*)  
  RewriteRule (.\*) /%1/%2?id=%3 [L]
```

Where %1 would match 'abc', %2 would match 'xyz', and %3 456adf646asdf in your example.

Is mod_rewrite installed?

Comment: this is working but not show id...       http://staging.rdfs.in/ride/linkedin/?id=

Comment: Please post back the Rewrite rule you used.

Comment: Thank you for formatting the code. Just joined yesterday, that's my next lesson.

Comment: Thanks, Mr. Tanstaafi and Mr. AKAM for response but this error show after both changes "The requested URL /abc/xyz/232323asf was not found on this server."

Comment: try this: 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/abc/xyz/(.*)/
RewriteRule (.*) /abc/xyz?id=%1 [L]
with url: example.com/ride/linkedin/12122/

Answer (score 0):

That won't work. Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^/abc/xyz/(.+)$ /abc/xyz?id=$1
```